# Images in ListView not shown on first opening

Tags: xaml, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using a ListView to display some images.

```
<ListView 
    CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Images}"
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    HasUnevenRows="true"
    SeparatorColor="Transparent"
    BackgroundColor="White" >

    ...

    <Image Source="{Binding}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
```

I am adding a List of UriImageSources to display the images.

```
foreach (var img in images) {
    res.Add(new UriImageSource() {
        Uri = new Uri(img),
        CachingEnabled = true
    });
}
```

The problem is, that the List does not show the images at the first time I open the XAML ContentPage. At the second time all images are cached and then the images are shown.

So, how can I preload the Images before binding?

Comment: Why not use FFimageLoading with its Caching Mechanism?

Comment: This happens when forms has the image not loaded yet and it doesn't know what size to set for the view. So the view is not shown. Try set some heightrequest/widthrequest to the image or to its container, put image inside a contentview (might need to set more layout properties to it) and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

As Bruno said, you could use FFimageLoading to your listview.
I wrote a demo, you could refer to it.

This is GIF of demo.

[image]

If you used FFimageLoading, first of all, you should refer to [this link](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/wiki/Xamarin.Forms-API) that prepare running environment.

Following is my code of demo.

`MainPage.xaml`

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:JobschedulerDemo"
         xmlns:ffimageloading="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Forms"
         x:Class="JobschedulerDemo.MainPage">

<StackLayout>
    <ListView 
        x:Name="listview"
          CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" 
          VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
          HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
          HasUnevenRows="true"
          SeparatorColor="Transparent"
          BackgroundColor="White" >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Fill" BackgroundColor="Olive">
                       <ffimageloading:CachedImage HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"
                            WidthRequest="300" HeightRequest="300"
                             DownsampleToViewSize="true"
                             Source = "{Binding LinkSource}">
                        </ffimageloading:CachedImage>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
 </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

`MainPage.xaml.cs`

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var grouped = new ObservableCollection<ImageLink>() {

            new ImageLink{LinkSource="http://loremflickr.com/600/600/nature?filename=simple.jpg" },
            new ImageLink{LinkSource="http://loremflickr.com/600/600/nature?filename=simple.jpg" },
            new ImageLink{LinkSource="http://loremflickr.com/600/600/nature?filename=simple.jpg" },
            new ImageLink{LinkSource="http://loremflickr.com/600/600/nature?filename=simple.jpg" },
        };
        listview.ItemsSource= grouped;
    }
}
```

`ImageLink`

```
public class ImageLink
{
    public ImageLink()
    {


    }

    public string LinkSource { get; set; }

}
```